# Which various versions of vampirism cure diseases?

Tags: vampire, meme

What do various stories and interpretations of the vampire meme say about its ability to cure diseases? It seems some versions of vampirism can cure diseases like myopia, and others that you can never be cured due to the fact you're now dead.

**What are the main classifications of vampirism? What are the best examples of how each works?**

Comment: I don't think this question is specific enough. If left in its current form, you're asking for a list of works that involve vampirism curing diseases. If you were to change it to "Is there a work out there that addresses this" then the answer is going to be "Yes there is."

Comment: @OghmaOsiris - It does, in spirit, seem to ask for a **classification**, with a singular example of each class. But it could definitely be majorly improved to make that spirit clearer.

Comment: Note for the interested: this question [has been re-asked](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/233684/19561) in more focused form.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Twilight - The transformation process "perfects" the physical form; most vampires were turned relatively young, and in the rare cases of older humans being turned (Marcus, Eleazar, Alistair) the process takes years off their appearance. Vampires gain extremely attuned senses, photographic memories with perfect recall, and any diseases, injuries, even cosmetic flaws are erased. In addition, each vampire brings forth some core trait which is strengthened; in many cases this becomes a supernatural "power" like Edward's or Aro's mind-reading, Bella's mental shield, Jasper's ability to affect emotion, or Alice's visions of the future. The use of vampire conversion to heal injury and disease is mentioned many times through the series; The Cullen family, with the exception of Alice and Jasper, is made up of people Carlisle encountered who were at the point of death. Edward was dying of Spanish flu, and Esme (tried to commit suicide by jumping off a cliff), Rose (raped and beaten by her fiance and his friends) and Emmett (mauled by a bear) were mortally injured in various ways, as was Bella after giving birth to Renesmee. You don't have to be dying to be turned, but Carlisle (and his "children") would never turn someone who had any other choice.

True Blood - Vampirism is a cure for most wounds, and increases acuity of the senses (which would generally indicate that deafness, blindness, myopia, etc are curable afflictions as well). However, other than a paler complexion, vampires maintain the form they had in life; for instance, Eddie, from Season 1, remains overweight after being turned. Most other vampires we see are close to peak fitness because they were so before being turned (Bill was a Civil War soldier, Eric was a Viking warlord), but you could be bald, have missing teeth, etc, and being turned would not fix these. As proof it can heal injury and/or sickness, Eric was at the point of death when Godric turned him (in fact in the show he was on his own funeral pyre when Godric caught up to him and his men). They haven't covered most situations of disease or extreme injury; nobody ever beats cancer by being turned, and we never see someone lose an arm or leg, and then get turned and have it grow back (though Jessica was a virgin when she was turned, and suffers the somewhat comical embarrassment of having her hymen keep growing back). In one of the books, there is a mention of a mentally damaged vampire, who is implied to be Elvis, post-overdose, so apparently it can't fix *everything*. Vampire blood can heal humans without turning them as well; Sookie gets saved by Bill's blood many times in the series, and Lafayette has an infected gunshot wound healed by drinking Eric's blood in Season 2.

Underworld - Vampires remain technically alive (beating heart, body heat, metabolic processes); the condition of vampirism is caused by a beneficial viral infection. We never see the transformation to pure vampire in the movies, so the timeline and exact process isn't clear, but Viktor was an old, probably sick man when he was turned, and Michael was near death from being shot when Selene bit him to turn him into a hybrid. The hybrid process happens pretty quickly (a minute, maybe two); we don't know if vampirization normally happens that quickly, but becoming a full werewolf after being bitten requires a full moon, so it can take days or weeks to get the full effect. In addition to increased physical prowess, the senses are sharpened (much like in most other universes) so you never see a blind, deaf or glasses-wearing vampire.

Anne Rice (Interview With A Vampire) - Vampirism will save you from most physical injury or infirmity; in fact the act of turning requires draining the victim of blood, so if not turned (by giving them vampire blood) the victim would die. Much like Twilight it also perfects the physical body, but unlike Twilight vampirization generally does not affect the appearance of age; you'll look good, but still look 10, or 30, or 60.

Comment: In Twilight, if a person is turned before reaching childhood, they remain a child both physically and mentally. This isn't a problem with older children who have sufficient maturity (say 10 and over) but younger children and especially infants, become dangerous and uncontrollable - they lack the ability to understand consequences.