# What is the first work that depicts vampirism curing or 'perfecting' somone's physical state?

Tags: history-of, vampire

It's a common trope that once someone has become a vampire, that their minor physical ailments are resolved or cured entirely.

What is the first instance of this occurring?

Comment: This question was [previously asked](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/11381/which-various-versions-of-vampirism-cure-diseases) but as it was unclear, this new version has been asked.

Comment: perhaps this could help https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_vampire_traits_in_folklore_and_fiction.